# Trying to get ninject and signalR to work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, signalr

In my NinjectWebCommon.cs file, under the `RegisterServices` method I have the following:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IProfileRepository>().To<ProfileRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IMatchUpService>().To<MatchUpService>();
            kernel.Bind<ISoloUserRepository>().To<SoloUserRepository>();
           SignalR.GlobalHost.DependencyResolver =  new SignalR.Ninject.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        }
```

I am trying to inject SoloUserRepository into my hub class, here is my hub class:

```
public class MatchMaker : Hub
    {
        [Inject]
        private ISoloUserRepository soloUsers { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason when I try to use the `soloUsers` object in my Hub class, i get `object reference not set to instance of an object` because the `soloUsers` object is never being instantiated or, in other words, not injected.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a `private` property, and Ninject by default doesn't inject private properties.

So either you make your property `public` or you can enable non public property injection with:

```
kernel.Settings.InjectNonPublic = true;
```

I'm not familiar with the dependency injection in SignalR (so maybe it's not supported) but you should always prefer constructor injection so your `Hub` should be like:

```
public class MatchMaker : Hub
{    
    private readonly ISoloUserRepository soloUsers;

    public MatchMaker(ISoloUserRepository soloUsers) 
    {
        this.soloUsers = soloUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: As this answer is marked as accepted i assume it solved the issue of @anthonypliu which means ninject can be used in  signalr and its hubs. Going to try it out now